# Is it possible to set multiple icons in the address bar with a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a listener that gets an array of data and uses one of the items from the array to set an icon in the addressbar using `pageAction.setIcon()`, which works fine.  Currently it places the other icons in a popup that's activated on click.  I'd like to just put all of the icons in the address bar, but if I call `setIcon()` again it clobbers the first one and only my last icon shows up.

Is there any way (either through `pageAction.setIcon()` or some other way) to put multiple icons in the address bar from a single extension?

Comment: I suspect not. There may be a bug report where a Chromium developer states that they will never support this functionality, but I can't seem to find any such report now. (If I do, I'll post it as an answer.) Your current solution seems like the best possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

One extension can add only one `browser_action` or `page_action` to the UI. It is mentioned in the [documentation for `manifest.json`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html).